# Ceiling fan will not turn off

Tags: ceiling-fan

I have a ceiling fan with NO wall switch to turn it off. It works by remote, (I have an old house and they have it set up this way). I changed the battery and it still wont shut off. Its a Hunter Fan with no Light.

Comment: Is there a pull chain switch located on the fan?

Comment: Has this always been a problem or a new one?  Have you changed anything?

Comment: Try turning the circuit breaker for the fan off and then on again.

Comment: Hunter receiver in one of my Hunter fans required cycling the breaker to reset the receiver. No wall switch on our fans was a mistake.

Comment: Agree with @JimStewart here.   I'm hard put to think of any other household item that runs off a remote for which there's no hard switch or at least the ability to unplug from the wall (e.g. TV set).